# MySQL: SQL insert query to duplicate data in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table say `table1(id, col2, col3)`, and I want to duplicate all data of `id 1` but with different `id` say `11` (id is not auto generated column). I wrote the following sql query which is not working for me (giving syntax error):

```
INSERT INTO table1(
id,
col2,
col3
)
VALUES (

SELECT 11 , col2, col3
FROM table1 WHERE id=1
)
```

Comment: And in what way has this not worked? What error did you get?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Comment: The problem is : don't put the "VALUES" keyword" when using insert... select

Comment: removed the VALUES keyword and put the id condition but still not working. Now getting the error #1054 - Unknown column 'col2' in 'field list'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use the "VALUES" keyword

```
INSERT INTO table1(
id,
col2,
col3
)


SELECT 11 , col2, col3
FROM table1
WHERE id = 1
```

EDIT :

Check if you're working with the right column names :

```
DESC table1;
```

Comment: +1, the only one that mentioned you need the where clause of id = 1 to make this work.

Comment: removed the VALUES keyword but still not working. Now getting the error #1054 - Unknown column 'col2' in 'field list'

Comment: @gmuhammad what happens if you write `select 11, col2, col3 from table1` ?

Comment: getting the same error #1054 - Unknown column 'col2' in 'field list'

Comment: @gmuhammad then what gives `DESC table1`;

Comment: Oh I got it. I am referring to another db with the same table name but different number of columns. Thanks Raphaël Althaus. It's working now.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table1(
id,
col2,
col3
)
SELECT 11 , col2, col3
FROM table1
WHERE table1.id = 1
```

OR if you need more something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1(id, col2, col3)
SELECT (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1) + 1 , col2, col3
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) with `WHERE id = 1`:

```
INSERT INTO table1(id, col2, col3)
SELECT '1' + id , col2, col3
FROM table1
WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT` takes `VALUES` or `SELECT`, not both.

```
INSERT INTO table1( id, col2, col3 ) 
SELECT 11 , col2, col3 
FROM table1 
WHERE id = 1
```